# Collect multiple json objects from data attribute

Tags: jquery, json

I have 3 button elements on which I have assigned the same type of JSON objects to a data attribute. I imagined that I would be able to get those objects into an array, but I only get a single object from the first match.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var configs = $("button[id*='alertbtn']").data('config');
```

I have verified that my selector

```
$("button[id*='alertbtn']")
```

targets the correct three elements.

Is it possible to achive what I want using a single line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One *line*? Yes. One *function call*? No. :-)

```
var configs = $("button[id*='alertbtn']").map(function() { return $(this).data('config'); }).get();
```

More readably:

```
var configs = $("button[id*='alertbtn']")
                .map(function() { return $(this).data('config'); })
                .get();
```

That uses [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to get the set of config objects, then [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get the jQuery set's contents as an array.

---

It's one *readable* line in ES2015 and above:

```
let configs = Array.from($("button[id*='alertbtn']")).map(e = > $(e).data('config'));
```